# Module compiled with Swift 5.3.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1.3 compiler

Tags: ios, swift

i am trying to use AcceptCardSDK Pod i tried to re-install the pod and make build libraries for distribution = yes but the error still exists

Comment: What Xcode version are you using?

Comment: show your error message like screenshot , logs or something from Xcode or terminal

Comment: @matt Xcode Version 11.3.1

Comment: Yes, that would explain it. You need to use an earlier version of the pod, or else update your Xcode (current version is 12.2).

Comment: @matt i tried to use an earlier version of the pod, it now works, Thank you

Comment: Yeah, of course the downside is if they've made actual improvements since then... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the current version of this pod in Xcode 11.3, because the pod was compiled with Swift 5.3 but Xcode 11.3 stops at Swift 5.1.

Either use an earlier version of the pod (if there is one) or else update your Xcode (current version is 12.2).